# Ggplot and Shiny Questions

Tags: r, shiny

Hey guys I'm working on my first shiny app and am having fun with it.  However I've come to a halt.  I've create a pretty basic game simulation for the NBA.  So you pick two teams and they play and it gives you a final score.  I want to be able to put in a graph that shows the score as the game progresses (So each teams current points is plotted every 1 or 2 seconds).

I'm having trouble getting the graph to change each time the teams are submitted and I can't figure out how to fix this.  I imagine I have to make it reactive or put the graphing functions into a function but I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm also curious as to how to allow my submit button to work even if the input variables aren't changed.  That way you can pick two teams and simulate lets say 7 games in a row.  However I have to change the teams each time to be able to resubmit.

Here's my code:

**UI.R**

```
##UI.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("NBA Simulation","NBA Simulation"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(


      helpText("Choose two different NBA teams to simulate a game!"),

      selectInput("team1",
                  label="Team 1:",
                  choices=list("Atlanta Hawks"=1, "Boston Celtics"=2, "Brooklyn Nets"=3, "Charlotte Hornets"=4, "Chicago Bulls"=5, "Cleveland Cavaliers"=6, "Dallas Mavericks"=7, "Denver Nuggets"=8, "Detroit Pistons"=9, "Golden State Warriors"=10, "Houston Rockets"=11, "Indiana Pacers"=12, "LA Clippers"=13, "LA Lakers"=14, "Memphis Grizzlies"=15, "Miami Heat"=16, "Milwaukee Bucks"=17, "Minnesota Timberwolves"=18, "New Orleans Pelicans"=19, "New York Knicks"=20, "OKC Thunder"=21, "Orlando Magic"=22, "Philadelphia 76ers"=23, "Phoenix Suns"=24, "Portland Trailblazers"=25, "Sacramento Kings"=26, "San Antonio Spurs"=27, "Toronto Raptors"=28, "Utah Jazz"=29, "Washington Wizards"=30),
                  selected=1),

      selectInput("team2",
                  label="Team 2:",
                  choices=list("Atlanta Hawks"=1, "Boston Celtics"=2, "Brooklyn Nets"=3, "Charlotte Hornets"=4, "Chicago Bulls"=5, "Cleveland Cavaliers"=6, "Dallas Mavericks"=7, "Denver Nuggets"=8, "Detroit Pistons"=9, "Golden State Warriors"=10, "Houston Rockets"=11, "Indiana Pacers"=12, "LA Clippers"=13, "LA Lakers"=14, "Memphis Grizzlies"=15, "Miami Heat"=16, "Milwaukee Bucks"=17, "Minnesota Timberwolves"=18, "New Orleans Pelicans"=19, "New York Knicks"=20, "OKC Thunder"=21, "Orlando Magic"=22, "Philadelphia 76ers"=23, "Phoenix Suns"=24, "Portland Trailblazers"=25, "Sacramento Kings"=26, "San Antonio Spurs"=27, "Toronto Raptors"=28, "Utah Jazz"=29, "Washington Wizards"=30),
                  selected=2),

      submitButton("Submit")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h1("Final Result"),
      htmlOutput("simLogo1"),
      htmlOutput("simResult"),
      htmlOutput("simLogo2"),
      plotOutput("scrPlot")
    )

)
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
##server.R
source("TwoTeamSimulation.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$simResult <- renderText({
    team1 <- input$team1
    team2<- input$team2
    simgame(team1,team2)
  })
  output$simLogo1 <- renderText({
    team1 <- input$team1
    sprintf('<img src="%s.jpg" height="150" width="350"/>', team1)
  })
  output$simLogo2 <- renderText({
    team2 <- input$team2
    sprintf('<img src="%s.jpg" height="150" width="350"/>', team2)
  })
  output$scrPlot <- renderPlot({
    return(graphsp)
  })
})
```

**TwoTeamSimulation.R**

```
##TwoTeamSimulation.R
Stats<-NBA.Stats
Stats

library(ggplot2)

simgame<-function(team1,team2){
  #assign variables
  team1name<<-Stats[team1,1]
  team2name<<-Stats[team2,1]
  #find total attempts
  totalAtt1<-Stats[team1,3]+Stats[team1,5]+(Stats[team1,7]/2)+Stats[team1,8]+Stats[team1,9]
  #Find the probability of attempting a 2 pt, 3 pt, ft, and turnover.
  twoPtP1<-Stats[team1,3]/totalAtt1
  threePtP1<-Stats[team1,5]/totalAtt1
  FtP1<-(Stats[team1,7]/2)/totalAtt1
  TOP1<-Stats[team1,8]/totalAtt1
  ORB1<-Stats[team1,9]/totalAtt1
  #set team1 points to 0
  team1pt<-0
  #set team1 possession counter
  i1<-0
  #create score progression
  t1sp<-c()
  #Now we start to run through the simulation
  while(i1 <= 100){
    #Randomly select what action is taken
    action<-sample(1:4, 1, prob=c(twoPtP1, threePtP1, FtP1, TOP1))
    #Action = 1? Two Point Attempt
    if(action==1){
      #1 = Make, 2= Miss
      twoMake1<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team1,2],(1-Stats[team1,2])))
      if(twoMake1==1){
        team1pt<-team1pt+2
        t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
        i1<-i1+1
      }
      if(twoMake1==2){
        oreb21<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(ORB1,(1-ORB1)))
        if(oreb21==1){
          i1<-i1
        }
        if(oreb21==2){
          t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
          i1<-i1+1
        }
      }
    }
    #Action = 2? Three Point Attempt
    if(action==2){
      #1 = Make, 2= Miss
      threeMake1<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team1,4],(1-Stats[team1,4])))
      if(threeMake1==1){
        team1pt<-team1pt+3
        t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
        i1<-i1+1
      }
      if(threeMake1==2){
        oreb31<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(ORB1,(1-ORB1)))
        if(oreb31==1){
          i1<-i1
        }
        if(oreb31==2){
          t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
          i1<-i1+1
        }
      }
    }
    #Action = 3? Free Throw Attempt
    if(action==3){
      #free throw 1 and 2
      ft11<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team1,6],(1-Stats[team1,6])))
      ft21<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team1,6],(1-Stats[team1,6])))
      if(ft11==1 & ft21==1){ #Makes both
        team1pt<-team1pt+2
        t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
        i1<-i1+1
      }
      if(ft11==1 & ft21==2){ #Makes first, misses second
        team1pt<-team1pt+1
        t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
        i1<-i1+1
      }
      if(ft11==2 & ft21==1){ #Misses first, makes second
        team1pt<-team1pt+1
        t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
        i1<-i1+1
      }
      if(ft11==2 & ft21==2){ #Misses both
        t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
        i1<-i1+1
      }
    }
    if(action==4){ #Turnover so nothing happens besides them losing a possesion
      t1sp <- c(team1pt,t1sp)
      i1<-i1+1
    }
  }
  #find total attempts
  totalAtt2<-Stats[team2,3]+Stats[team2,5]+(Stats[team2,7]/2)+Stats[team2,8]+Stats[team2,9]
  #Find the probability of attempting a 2 pt, 3 pt, ft, and turnover.
  twoPtP2<-Stats[team2,3]/totalAtt2
  threePtP2<-Stats[team2,5]/totalAtt2
  FtP2<-(Stats[team2,7]/2)/totalAtt2
  TOP2<-Stats[team2,8]/totalAtt2
  ORB2<-Stats[team2,9]/totalAtt2
  #set team1 points to 0
  team2pt<-0
  #set team1 possession counter
  i2<-0
  #set team2 score progression
  t2sp<-c()
  #Now we start to run through the simulation
  while(i2 <= 100){
    #Randomly select what action is taken
    action<-sample(1:4, 1, prob=c(twoPtP2, threePtP2, FtP2, TOP2))
    #Action = 1? Two Point Attempt
    if(action==1){
      #1 = Make, 2= Miss
      twoMake2<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team2,2],(1-Stats[team2,2])))
      if(twoMake2==1){
        team2pt<-team2pt+2
        t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
        i2<-i2+1
      }
      if(twoMake2==2){
        oreb22<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(ORB2,(1-ORB2)))
        if(oreb22==1){
          i2<-i2
        }
        if(oreb22==2){
          t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
          i2<-i2+1
        }
      }
    }
    #Action = 2? Three Point Attempt
    if(action==2){
      #1 = Make, 2= Miss
      threeMake2<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team2,4],(1-Stats[team2,4])))
      if(threeMake2==1){
        team2pt<-team2pt+3
        t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
        i2<-i2+1
      }
      if(threeMake2==2){
        oreb32<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(ORB2,(1-ORB2)))
        if(oreb32==1){
          i2<-i2
        }
        if(oreb32==2){
          t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
          i2<-i2+1
        }
      }
    }
    #Action = 3? Free Throw Attempt
    if(action==3){
      #free throw 1 and 2
      ft12<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team2,6],(1-Stats[team2,6])))
      ft22<-sample(1:2,1,prob=c(Stats[team2,6],(1-Stats[team2,6])))
      if(ft12==1 & ft22==1){ #Makes both
        team2pt<-team2pt+2
        t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
        i2<-i2+1
      }
      if(ft12==1 & ft22==2){ #Makes first, misses second
        team2pt<-team2pt+1
        t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
        i2<-i2+1
      }
      if(ft12==2 & ft22==1){ #Misses first, makes second
        team2pt<-team2pt+1
        t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
        i2<-i2+1
      }
      if(ft12==2 & ft22==2){ #Misses both
        t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
        i2<-i2+1
      }
    }
    if(action==4){ #Turnover so nothing happens besides them losing a possesion
      t2sp <- c(team2pt,t2sp)
      i2<-i2+1
    }

  }

  result1<-sprintf("<h4><strong> %s Final: </h4></strong> %s", Stats[team1,1],team1pt)
  result2<-sprintf("<h4><strong> %s Final: </h4></strong> %s", Stats[team2,1],team2pt)
  team1sp <<- rev(t1sp)
  team2sp <<- rev(t2sp)
  gamescore <<- cbind(team1sp,team2sp)
  paste(result1, result2, sep="<br>")

}

simgame(2,7)




#GRAPHING
comsc<-c(team1sp,team2sp) 

teamid <- c(rep("Team 1", length(team1sp)), rep("Team 2", length(team2sp)))

scoringprog <- data.frame(pos=rep(1:101, 2), score=comsc, team=teamid)
scoringprog

graphsp <- ggplot(data=scoringprog, aes(x=pos, y=comsc, color=team)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=team))+
  geom_point(aes(color=team))+
  xlab("Possesion")+
  ylab("Score")+
  ggtitle("Scoring Progression")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Team Name", 
                      breaks=c("Team 1", "Team 2"), 
                      labels=c(as.character(team1name), as.character(team2name)))
graphsp
```